# XAML animation moving countdown

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers

I have the following TextBlock which will be a moving countdown timer:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="countdown">
      <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <TranslateTransform x:Name="countdownTransform" />
      </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
 </TextBlock>
```

The following triggers should move the TextBlock and set the countdown text:

```
<Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="PlayButton" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
         <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="songProgressBar" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                                     From="0:30:0" To="0" Duration="0:30:0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="countdownTransform" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" AutoReverse="True" 
                                     From="0.0" To="{Binding ElementName=countdown, Path=Width}" Duration="0:30:0" />
               </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

However, the DoubleAnimation's From property doesn't accept (obviously) TimeSpan and for the second trigger, To property isn't binding to the TextBlock's Width. Is there a custom type of animation that accepts TimeSpan at To property?

I want to be able to do this in XAML, I know this is possible in c# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Width` of the TextBlock is `NaN` unless you explicitly set it, and `NaN` is not a valid value for the `To` property of a DoubleAnimation. You should have seen the error message in VS output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value='NaN'
>   BindingExpression:Path=Width; DataItem='TextBlock' (Name='countdown');
>   target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=62632450); target
>   property is 'To' (type 'Nullable`1')

You could instead bind to `ActualWidth`:

```
<DoubleAnimation ... To="{Binding ElementName=countdown, Path=ActualWidth}" />
```

For the other animation: If the duration is a constant value, why not simply set `From="30"`? Otherwise you would also have to have a ProgressBar that takes a TimeSpan for `Value`, `Minimum`, `Maximum` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually the duration is not a constant a value, it's binding to a resource: Duration="{Binding XPath=time}". The first animation is working.

Comment: Why can't you bind to [TimeSpan.TotalMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) like `Duration="{Binding XPath=time.TotalMinutes}"`?